# What valuable resources or features could a city state have to keep themselves independent and a dominant local power?

Tags: natural-resources, medieval, trade

Trying to build a coastal region of feudal/renaissance city states surrounded by small feudal kingdoms. Looking for resources that are valuable beyond their access to sea, its bounty and the trade that comes with it. Also looking for features beyond having big walls and/or being difficult to access.

For example I read somewhere that ancient Athens had access to a silver mine, which I assume helped them significantly.

Anything unique or a bit off the wall is very welcome, but nothing magical or unrealistic please.

Comment: we don't compile arbitrary lists, as those are opinion based. We solve specific worldbuilding problems.

Comment: Just looking for help my friend if you want to point me in the right direction.

Comment: sound like venice to me, for valuable resource.....silver and......guano? if its tropical or warm enough island then spice and pearl.

Comment: or you want finished product like venetian glass?

Comment: Both, anything that would give a society a leg up economically or strategically. Spices are a go to one but I didn’t think about something like glass so thank you for that.

Comment: Why don't use historical examples such as venice ? It was a city state, even if it had colony/territory outside venice itself, and was sourrounded by smallish kingdoms, as Italy wasn't unified. Same goes for other merchant republics.

Comment: @Kepotx: The entire western and central Europe consisted of smallish kingdoms, princedoms, duchies, counties, and so on. Large-ish kingdoms emerged in the late Middle Ages, first France, then Spain; but central Europe remained fragmented into a bewildering puzzle of smallish states throughout the Renaissance and well into the Modern period.

Comment: Yes, Athens had the mines at Laurion. But other contemporary city-states didn't have such mines, and still prospered: Corinth, Syracuse, Carthage, Tyre, or Miletus for example.

Comment: @Kepotx: I am aware of that, genuinely trying to just get a broader, more unique range of ideas that could give my world a bit more depth.

Answer (score 1):

The city is 50 years ahead technologically because they discover (accidentally) a new alloy (in a mine under the city or trying to make something else) which is stronger and lighter than anything else at the time.
Then they use this new alloy to build the armor of the soldier and they found they can use it to build also the ships (at least give them some protection) and better weapons.